# Notepad++ - highlight custom keywords

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way for Notepad++ to highlight syntax with user added keywords, WITHOUT defining new language?
I'd like to add highlighting for TODO/TBD/FIXME and some other, project specific keywords. Is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ : Custom Syntax Highlighting for .txt files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877646/notepad-custom-syntax-highlighting-for-txt-files), [User defined syntax highlight in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5046543/62576), [Notepad++ Custom Language Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5677962/62576), and about a dozen others. Please do at least a basic search (or view the Related questions that appear as you're typing your question and adding tags) before posting.

Comment: Okay, but all these "duplicate" links are suggesting defining new language. The question is if this is possible without language redefinition...

Comment: These two solutions helped me. http://superuser.com/questions/567703/permanently-highlight-all-occurrences-of-text-in-notepad

Comment: The idea was it should be. But it isn't possible. There seem to be bugs when you try to create your custom language via GUI. Any answers you find online will be a circumvention of those bugs (like editing xml files).

Answer (score 11):

For those that are visting this page (by a google search for example), there is an answer for the Ruby language given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430884/adding-keywords-to-ruby-syntax-highlighting-for-notepad). But as it works the same way for every other language, `BoltClock` answer is suitable for [given] language.

In short:
Go to  **Settings** > **Style Configurator** > Choose language > Click at **KEYWORD** / **INSTRUCTION** and add your own keyword.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work for TODO's in comments. It chooses the default comment color.

Comment: I don't have the words to describe how annoyingly difficult that is to find.

Answer (score 1):

From the blog article [How to Organise your life with just a text file](http://web.archive.org/web/20150525160906/http://bizgenius.co.in/one-of-the-best-ways-to-organise-your-life-is-to-use-a-text-file/):

You can add *keywords* to Python with `Settings > Style Configurator`

I use the `Now`, `Soon`, and `Later` keywords (among others) to organize my projects. I chose Python because the folding is defined with Indents. You can add your own keywords and choose the color highlight for foreground and background colors.